# Filter with Price Not shown in Navigation Layer

Tags: magento2, price, layered-navigation

I have a simple product under the same category with different prices and my store is multilingual (i use the same currency euro), I just configured the price as manual and I checked that price is filterable with results but it's not shown to filter

Answer (score 0):

1. Check (Use in Layered Navigation) property in your price attribute. `Stores->Attributes->Product->Price->Storefront properties`

[image]

2. Reindex and clean the cache.
3. If it doesn't work follow this : [Mageplaza Price Filter configuration](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-price-filter-price-navigation-magento-2.html)